# Two circles are tangent to each other, find the ratio of line that splits the area into $1:2$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> There is one circle with radius $1$. There is another circle with
>   radius $2$. They are tangent to each other and touch each other at
>   point $c$. A line through $c$ splits the area formed  by the two
>   circles into two parts. The ratio of the two parts is $1:2$. In what
>   ratio does the line split the area of the smaller circle (the circle
>   with radius $1$)?

[image]
This was one of the questions in last year's AMC. I have no idea how to solve it. I thought that you could try and work out the of the two parts of the smaller circle and figure out what the ratio was between them. I tried that but failed. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If anyone has a picture for this problem, could you please edit my question and upload the picture?

Comment: Are the two circles and dividing chords similar figures?

Comment: @Henry Well, two circles are always similar right? I don't know about the chords.

Comment: I would have thought the chords had the same angle with the tangent, and so the same angles with the radii.

Comment: @Henry I don't know... sorry I don't know much about geometry.

Comment: Apart from notation, it looks the same. Will delete comment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Your comment inspired me to add a geographic codicil to my answer.

Comment: Your Australias will be a nice addition to my "scaling argument" collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Regions P and S are similar, as are regions Q and R. And the area of the right-hand circle is four times the area of the left-hand circle. So $P = 4S$ and $Q = 4R$.

And we are told that $Q+S = 2(P+R)$.

Substituting, $4R+S = 2(4S+R)$. You can take it from there.

**Updated to add:** Riffing on André's comment (now deleted), this doesn't just work for circles. For instance, it works for Australias too:

[image]

Comment: Yes I can! Thanks its all clear now.